# Adding to .cvsignore a previously committed 'target' directory

Tags: windows, eclipse, cvs, ignore

We are trying to add to **`.cvsignore`** a previously and accidentally committed **`target`** directory (containing binary files).

It just does not work. Each time we **synchronize with repository or commit** (using Eclipse), the **`target` directory is included...**

We are not sure how to proceed. Can anyone please provide advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a file or directory has been committed to the repository, `.cvsignore` will not work. I'm pretty sure this is a limitation of CVS, but I can't find a reference. The only way I know to proceed is to manually remove the files from the repository (as in, go to the server file system and delete them).

Comment: Thanks. Are there guidelines as to how to do that? Perhaps CVS built-in commands already exist?

Comment: First, always always always make a backup of your repository before touching it directly. When I've had to do this, I've just gone to the repository server's file system and deleted the unwanted files directly (and the corresponding Attic file(s), too). It's a little dangerous, so be ver careful.

Comment: http://www.gtwiki.org/mwiki/index.php?title=Purging_old_versions_in_the_CVS_repository suggests that you might be able to use the *cvs admin* command to accomplish it, but I don't know much about that.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid messing with the repository directly, I

- mv myFileToIgnore myFileToIgnore.save
- cvs remove myFileToIgnore
- cvs commit myFileToIgnore
- mv myfile.save myFileToIgnore

This moves the file out of the way so that I can remove it from the repository the cvs friendly way then puts it back where I need it to be.

If I have a bunch of files to do this to (ex: *.counter) I would save them in a directory so I can use wildcards to save and restore them.

HTH

Comment: This is brilliant and makes it a lot less nerve-wracking than full out deleting the files on the server. I didn't use command line, but did this through Eclipse - rename the file, commit directory (removes file), rename file back, go to commit again and mark the file for .cvsignore (add a wildcard to only have to do this step once if files are of similar filename structure). Very handy for build files.

Answer (score 2):

This is a few years late, but if you have access to the CVS command line binaries, you could remove the target directory recursively using this command:

```
cvs remove -fR target
```

Once the files have been removed, check in the changes:

```
cvs ci -m "removing target dir" .
```

Finally, update the .cvsignore file to ignore the target directory.

And yes, I'm still forced to use CVS in 2015 and I have to deal with these issues. Hoping this answer helps folks in similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the CVS server (you are therefore not able to delete the files on your own), you can follow the following steps to remove the files from the repo:

- revert ".cvsignore" to its initial state (it did not contain "target", in your case)
- move the "target" directory somewhere else (or remove it if you don't need it or can generate it afterwards)
- commit the deletion, do not commit the altered .cvsignore
- revert ".cvsignore" to the correct state (add "target", in your case)